# Corona SDK Animate a newImageRect

Tags: coronasdk

I am wanting a game object with both physics as well as animation sequences. I want to animate my character with a sprite sheet with predefined sequences while taking advantage of gravity, velocity, and other physics effects.

Is it possible to to add animation sequences to a `newImageRect`. Or add physics to a `newSprite`? Or join a sprite to a rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

To create an animation in Corona SDK, it's best to use this [resource](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)

You can connect the animation using this code

```
 display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

 -- lua data file that Texture packer published
 -- it contains the data required by newImageSheet
 -- and also contains a function to retrieve frames
 -- by their names sheetInfo:getFrameIndex("sprite")
 local sheetInfo = require("spritesheet")

 -- init the image sheet
 local myImageSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "spritesheet.png", 
 sheetInfo:getSheet() )

 local sequenceData = {
 -- set up anmiation
  { 
    name="walk",        -- name of the animation (used with setSequence)
    sheet=myImageSheet, -- the image sheet
    start=sheetInfo:getFrameIndex("capguy/walk/0001"), -- name of the first frame
    count=8,            -- number of frames
    time=1000,          -- speed
    loopCount=0         -- repeat
  },
}

 capguy = display.newSprite( myImageSheet, sequenceData )
 -- set initial position and direction
 capguy.x = 160
 capguy.y = 300
 direction = 1
  -- start walking animation
 capguy:setSequence("walk")
 capguy:play()
```

For physics - [Physics Editor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the sprite sheet wasn't acting the way that I wanted it to because it wasn't added to the world. This line fixed the problem. `world:insert(capguy)`